# what unity of measurement is used in st_buffer(g,d) for the distance in mySql?

Tags: geometry, spatial-query, mysql-5.6

I have this spatial query in mysql:

select st_intersects(st_buffer(point(8.429614,45.017725),0.05),shape)

where shape is a column in db with geometry format.
I don't understand what unity of measurement is used for the distance in st_buffer function. What represents 0.05, 5km?5miles?
I have the radius express in km. I red the answer for this question that is similar to mine: [What is the unit of measurement used in MySQL's spatial Buffer call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947376/what-is-the-unit-of-measurement-used-in-mysqls-spatial-buffer-call) but i dont'understand the unity of measurement used in my case.